# Recursive unitless element type

Tags: arrays, recursion, types, julia

I am trying to come up with a function that gives me the recursive unitless element type. So for example, to shorten it let's call it `ruet`, I would like to have:

```
A = zeros(5,5)
reut(A) == Float64
using Unitful
A = zeros(5,5)*1u"kg"
reut(A) == Float64
AA = [zeros(5,5) for i in 1:5]
reut(AA) == Array{Float64,2}
AofA = [copy(A) for i in 1:5]
reut(AofA) == Array{Float64,2}
using StaticArrays
AofSA = [@SVector [2.0,3.0] for i in 1:5]
reut(AofSA) == SVector{2,Float64}
AofuSA = [@SVector [2.0u"kg",3.0u"kg"] for i in 1:5]
reut(AofuSA) == SVector{2,Float64}
```

So basically strip away the units but still return the correct element type, which could be an array. It's the array part that's hard. I can recurse:

```
recursive_eltype(a) = recursive_eltype(eltype(a))
recursive_eltype{T<:Number}(a::Type{T}) = eltype(a)
```

and then get the unitless element type:

```
uEltype = recursive_eltype(u)
uEltypeNoUnits = typeof(one(uEltype))
```

but then this is always the number type, and I can't seem to find a good way to get back the array types when it's an array of arrays, i.e. this method is returning `Float64` in all of the examples above. I am wondering if dispatching on static arrays and using `similar_type` is required here.

Note that I would like the solution to, if possible, not have a requirement on Unitful.jl. Getting the unitless type for the number can be done via `one(u)`, so I think this should be possible.

(Somewhat related Julia issue: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/22216)

Comment: I am nearly sure you don't want something like: `reut(A) = eval(parse(replace(repr(eltype(A)), repr(recursive_eltype(A)), repr(typeof(one(recursive_eltype(A)))))))` but who knows? :)

Comment: I don't want to eval. I would like this to be inferrable.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with:

```
Base.@pure recursive_unitless_eltype(a) = recursive_unitless_eltype(eltype(a))
Base.@pure recursive_unitless_eltype{T<:StaticArray}(a::Type{T}) = similar_type(a,recursive_unitless_eltype(eltype(a)))
Base.@pure recursive_unitless_eltype{T<:Array}(a::Type{T}) = Array{recursive_unitless_eltype(eltype(a)),ndims(a)}
Base.@pure recursive_unitless_eltype{T<:Number}(a::Type{T}) = typeof(one(eltype(a)))
```

This still isn't fully generic, but works on quite a broad range of things.

Answer (score 1):

Using Julia version 0.6.2-something (code surely not very portable):

```
function _reut(T)
    try
        T.name == Quantity.body.body.body.name && return _reut(T.parameters[1])
        getfield(T.name.module, T.name.name){_reut.(collect(T.parameters))...}
    catch
        T
    end
end
reut(T) = _reut(eltype(T))
```

And the tests in the question pass. Still not inferrable, but replaced `eval` with `getfield(Module,Symbol)`. Where do you get these questions?

Comment: "Where do you get these questions?" Developing [DifferentialEquations.jl](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl) is an infinite source of questions on generic algorithms. This one [comes from a current issue](https://github.com/JuliaDiffEq/DifferentialEquations.jl/issues/219).

Comment: This solution does infer properly if you add `Base.@pure` to be function. Sweet! Can this be checked on v0.7/1.0?

Comment: Another way to make this infer is probably just to make it an `@generated` function.

Comment: Hmm, this isn't quite what I was looking for because it seems to require a dependency on Unitful.jl instead of just Base tools like `one` or `oneunit` to get the unitless type.